# LaraDock multiproject laravel 8 - installation issue

Tags: laravel, webserver, laradock

I am completely new to LaraDock. After hours of trying to dockerize existing Laravel 8 projects, I discovered LaraDock. I have installed it successfuly and the container is running in Docker. When I go to localhost, however I get 404 not found. I need help to correctly set up the web server conf files.

So far I have created a new .conf file in apache2/sites as well as nginx/sites (as I do not know which webserver is running on Mac Monterey with LaraDock).

So in apache2/sites the new project1.conf has the following lines:

```
ServerName project1.test
DocumentRoot /Users/paul/Sites/project1
```

And in nginx/sites the project1.conf:

```
server_name project1.test;
root /Users/paul/Sites/project1;
index index.php index.html index.htm;
```

In the browser project1.test also returns error 404 not found.

In several .conf files the normal path to apache hosted file (/var/www/) does not exist on Monterey.  Should I replace these instances by /Users/paul/Sites/ ?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

in laravel the document root should be /public on the end.

so it could be

```
/Users/paul/Sites/MeerkatSafaris/public
```

and / or

```
DocumentRoot /Users/paul/Sites/project1/public
```

but it is unclear which is the correct root in your question

Comment: For some reason I do not remember, the index.php in all my existing projects are in the root folder, not in public.

Comment: try the apache and/or nginx error logs, found in /var/log. Also the laravel error log is in /storage/logs - these should give you more info as to the problem. you can also change the .env file to show errors with APP_DEBUG=true

Comment: On Monterey, there is not folder www in etc.  So i guess that any path using etc/www in the .conf files will not work.  So location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ { root /var/www/letsencrypt/; log_not_found off; } in nginx/sites/project1.conf will fail.  Also the folder letsencrypt does not exist in the laradock folder.  So what is the correct path here?